# Our Daughters name

Tags: grammaticality, spelling, vowels

My daughters name is Iyzrayella (eyes-ray-ella) now my husband and I are wondering if we are grammatically correct in the way we spelled her name.

Comment: There's no grammar rules about how letters are pronounced. There's also no standard way to pronounce non-standard spellings like "iyz". But, if you want the first syllable pronounced like "eyes", then I'd have spelled it, "Ayzrayella". "Iyz" is more likely to be pronounced "is" or "ease", especially because it sounds like the country Israel.

Comment: Agreed, except that in the UK 'Ayz' would be pronounced to rhyme with 'haze'!

Answer (score 0):

Names do not follow rules.

The guidelines for converting written letters into sounds can help but for a name, it is up to the parents (and later the individual) how they want to say the name, and how they want to spell it.

If her name is Iyzrayella and that is pronounced *eyes-ray-ella*, you haven't broken any rules.

There are a collection of well-known names, for girls these include "Sarah", "Mary", "Elizabeth" and so on.  These names have standard pronunciations. But even here there are variations.  Some Sarahs are *sah-rah* and some are *say-rah".

There are other rare names and there are individual names which are unique creations by the parents.  You name looks like a variant of Israella, which derives from Israel (a biblical name and the name of a nation) with a feminizing ending -ella.  But this unfamiliar spelling will cause many people to struggle to pronounce it. I would have guessed that it is pronounced like Israel  *Iz-ray-ella*. Expect 90 years of "actually it's *eyes-ray-ella*"